# How Do I Force User to Enter A More Complete Postal Address in One Field for Google Maps Geocode?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I currently use Google Maps Geocode API to take an address and get Lat and Log from it. My dilemma is I only provide one field for the user to type in their address, but somehow get the user to type in a complete address (street number, street name, city, and state) because when they type in just a street number and street name it may pull up the wrong city/state because of a common street name. One example would be the address of 5943 Middle Road.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=5943+Middle+Rd
```

This brings up Wisconsin, however, the real/intended address that should pull up is in New York. Is there a way either on my end or through Google's APIs to know when an address doesn't provide enough information to pinpoint a location better?

EDIT: I realize the api call pulls up multiple results, but since the user isn't presented a way to select which one is correct, I'd like the first result to be the winner.

Comment: Perhaps use autocomplete.  See ["Best Practices When Geocoding Addresses"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices) in the Google Maps documentation.

Comment: This seems like a pretty good approach. Thank you :)